# Name of function $(1+x)^n-1$

Tags: numerical-methods, terminology, special-functions, floating-point

Is there any name for this formula

$$(1+x)^n-1$$

When working with floating point numbers this can be calculated with much better precision for very small $|x|<1$ values using Taylor series comparing to result from direct calculation approach. Still I need to name it somehow to move this to separate calculation class and don't like the name `OnePlusPoweredMinusOneFunction`.

Comment: Not an official name, but coming up with a name shouldn't be that hard... 'PreTaylorTransform'

Comment: It's a delta function. Maybe `deltaPowerAtOne.`

Comment: The function is the exponential $x^n$ function's transformation with the fixed point (1, 1) moved to (0, 0). is there any specific name for functions going through the (0, 0) point?

Comment: Why don't you name it for what it does? For example, `FloatPointCalculation` or something? I'm assuming this is programming related.

Comment: @JeelShah, It doesn't describe the formula we are calculating. I may have several classes for similar problems dealing with different functions later.

Comment: Some software implementations use `pow1pm1`

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, in what sense this is a delta function? You mean http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DeltaFunction.html?

Comment: `shiftedPower`, maybe?

Comment: It is the difference $f(1+x)-f(1)$, which is $(\Delta_x f)(1)$.  It is "the delta of a function," technically, not "a delta function."

Comment: (Where $\Delta_h f(x)$ is defined to be $f(x+h)-f(x)$.)

Comment: Thanks, @columbus8myhw. If I'll have a package of classes for functions returning small values for small arguments, `ShiftedPower` describes the function well in that context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are dealing with this numerically, use

```
expm1(n*log1p(x))
```

(if those functions are available in your math library) to get high precision results.

```
expm1(x)=exp(x)-1
```

and

```
log1p(x) = ln(1+x)
```

both for small `x` without cancellation.

Comment: Thanks, that solves my problem! One more knowledge gap covered.